# How to assign or get workspace's parent folder path and workspaceFolder's parent folder name

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

How to get worksface parent folder path  and workspaceFolder's parent folder name by nodejs in vs code.
This is my workspace : c:/mamp/htdocs/projects/src/main

But i want to access src folder like workspace.How do it?

```
//var main = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolder[0].uri.path;

//var src  = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolder[-1].uri.path; ??????

var main = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolder[0].uri.path;

const src = path.dirname(main);

return src;
```

Comment: Do you want just the `src` foldername?  If so, try `path.basename(path.dirname(main))`

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this:

```
var main = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolder[0].uri.path;
var src = path.dirname(main);
```

Comment: Not working:   var main = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolder[0].uri.path;
            const src = path.dirname(main);  return src;

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the `src` foldername, try

`var src  = path.basename(path.dirname(main));`